# jQuery append child nodes in for each

Tags: jquery, foreach

In the below code I'm trying to loop through each child node and append the child to another element - what is the correct syntax inside the loop?

```
$(this).children().each(    
    $(div).appendChild(this.childNodes.length - 1);
);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within the `each()` function, `this` refers to the thing you're iterating on, in this case the `children()`.  It's not the `this` of the original jQuery object.

Therefore:

```
$(this).children().each(function() {    
    $(div).appendChild($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function callback or anonymous function in `each` call:

```
$(this).children().each(function() {
    $(div).appendChild(this.childNodes.length - 1);
});
```

or

```
function doSomething() {
    $(div).appendChild(this.childNodes.length - 1);
}

$(this).children().each(doSomething);
```

I'm not sure if your code couldn't been improved but there is little I can say when I see only the small portion of it.